# Show Images to the page by reading from Stream

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, inputstream

I upload an image to a fileStream. Then I put it on a Image object. If I want to show this image to the page, which way should I follow ?

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))

**IMMEDIATE WINDOW**
image
{System.Drawing.Bitmap}
    [System.Drawing.Bitmap]: {System.Drawing.Bitmap}
    base {System.MarshalByRefObject}: {System.Drawing.Bitmap}
    Flags: 0x00013012
    FrameDimensionsList: {System.Guid[0x00000001]}
    Height: 0x0000012f
    HorizontalResolution: 95.9865952
    Palette: {System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette}
    PhysicalDimension: {Width = 988.0 Height = 303.0}
    PixelFormat: Format32bppArgb
    PropertyIdList: {int[0x00000005]}
    PropertyItems: {System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem[0x00000005]}
    RawFormat: {[ImageFormat: b96b3caf-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]}
    Size: {Width = 0x000003dc Height = 0x0000012f}
    Tag: null
    VerticalResolution: 95.9865952
    Width: 0x000003dc
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display image on a website, I would use a Generic Handler (.ashx) to read file stream and output directly to Response object. Adding cache headers would also prevent from reading file stream on every request.

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Use a picturebox container on winforms or similar component for webforms to display it. You also can add browser component to display image.